# How to convert a `org.w3c.dom.Node` into `org.w3c.dom.Comment`

Tags: java, xml, dom

In an application I read a XML into a `org.w3c.dom.Document`. I am then searching for specific nodes I want to remove.

```
<list>
  <item id="1" />
  <item id="2" bad="true">
    <item id="2.1" />
  </item>
  <item id="3" />
</list>
```

Currently I replace the node by a new `org.w3c.dom.Comment` containing some key information copied from the replaced node.

```
<list>
  <item id="1" />
  <!-- removed bad item with id=2 -->
  <item id="3" />
</list>
```

But I would rather like to add the full node and its substructure to the comment to not loose the information.

```
<list>
  <item id="1" />
  <!--
  <item id="2" bad="true">
    <item id="2.1" />
  </item>
  -->
  <item id="3" />
</list>
```

Is there any elegant way to convert the node into a comment with the option to convert the comment back to a node at a later point?

The only way I can currently think of would be to use a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to transform the node to a string and put that string into the comment element. But I think this would be quite clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly wrap some elements into a comment. I think that you should process like follows:

1. serialize the element you have to remove in a String,
2. insert a comment with the string obtain as data

It could be achieved that way, assuming that your XML has formerly been loaded in the `document` variable (as an `org.w3c.dom.Document` object):

```java
    Node e = document.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild();

    // final DOMSerializerImpl ds = new DOMSerializerImpl();
    final DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS) document
        .getImplementation().getFeature("LS", "3.0");
    final LSSerializer ser = ls.createLSSerializer();
    ser.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false);

    do {
    if (e.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        final Element el = (Element) e;
        if ("true".equals(el.getAttribute("bad"))) {
        // System.out.println("bad!!");
        final String sTextReplace = ser.writeToString(el);
        el.getParentNode().replaceChild(
            document.createComment(sTextReplace), el);
        }
        e = e.getNextSibling();
    }
    } while (e != null);

    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println(ser.writeToString(document));
```

The result this output is :

```xml
<list><item id="1"/><!--<item bad="true" id="2"><item id="2.1"/></item>--><item id="3"/></list>
```

Regarding *serialization*, I took some material from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer).

**Note:** be careful if ever the elements to be commented contain as well some comments... Comments can't be nested.

Comment: I had hoped for something more elegant but maybe this is just it. So I accept this as answer for now.